# Salesforce/Apex: How can I obtain the 15 digit ID for fields in a component?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a situation where I need to obtain the 15 digit (character) Id and field name for all the individual fields in my custom component.  I haven't had much luck searching the web or forum - at least not anything significant enough to aid me in my quest.

I am new to Salesforce and Apex, bur I suspect there is probably some function that one can call to get this information, but haven't been able to find it.

I would appreciate it if some enlightened Salesforce guru could point me in the right direction, either with a code snippet or a web site that explains the process in enough detail that I can figure it out.

Thanks
Dave J.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to get them as a one off you can copy them straight from the URL as you work through the setup pages. They will have the [00N](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#00N) key prefix, which is a CustomFieldDefinition.

To stay completely in Apex you can use the [Schema.DescribeFieldResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm). You can also [get a map with all the fields for an sObject](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm#apex_describe_object_all_fields).

Incidentally, there is a dedicated [Salesforce StackExchange site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=DescribeFieldResult) for Salesforce questions.